# Disabling enemy, getting a random number, teleport to that number as a coordinate, enabling the enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I have been trying to create a wave game where enemies keeps re-spawning after I have killed them. I have created the enemy and a gun to kill them with. Currently, I just disable the enemy object when it detects a collision with a bullet. And here comes the problem.

I want to get a random number and then teleport the enemy to that coordinate. And then re-enable the enemy so that it seems like it keeps re-spawning. How do I do that? Is there a better solution? I am using c#.

I am also a beginner to programming.

Here is the code:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Bullet)
{
    isEnemyDead = true;

    currentKillCount = currentKillCount + 1;

    

    if (isEnemyDead == true)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);

        Debug.Log("you have killed an enemy!");

        killCount.text = currentKillCount.ToString();
    }

    if(isEnemyDead == false)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    isEnemyDead = false;
}
```

Here I am disabling the object "Enemy" after it has detected a collision with a bullet. Then I want to get a random number and then teleport the game object to that position, and then enable the game object again so that it seems like it keeps re-spawning. That's what I want to do.

Comment: oh ok, i haven't really tried anything special. i have tried to search it up on Google and have found some answers, but none of them worked. what part of the code do you want? how do you post pictures on here?

Answer (score 0):

`gameObject.SetActive` deactivates all components of the object, It doesn't delete the object itself. Instead use `Object.Destroy` to remove it entirely.

I suggest you first reference the prefab of the enemy you're trying to place with `Public GameObject EnemyPrefab`

then
`Instantiate(EnemyPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0);` to place it

The coordinates of `Vector3` can be randomized by creating three instances of `Random.Next(0, 0)`, one for each coordinate. The two fields are the ranges of numbers that can generate, which you can decide yourself.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! i will try! ill update after i have tried it